# Manage processes on local machine using ASP .Net

Tags: c#, process, execution

I am trying to execute a process in a remote server from an ASP .Net web application (Note that the web application resides on the same server as the processes). The code I am running is the following:

```
 ConnectionOptions conO = new ConnectionOptions();
          //  conO.Username = txtUser.Text;
          // conO.Password = txtPassword.Text;

            ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + txtRemoteComputer.Text + @"\root\cimv2");

            System.Management.ManagementScope oMs = new System.Management.ManagementScope(path, conO);
            oMs.Connect();

            ObjectGetOptions opt = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementClass classInstance = new ManagementClass(oMs, path, opt);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = classInstance.GetMethodParameters("Create");
            inParams["CommandLine"] = txtPath.Text;
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
            lblInfo.Text = outParams["returnValue"].ToString() + " Process ID: {0}" + outParams["processId"].ToString();
```

However, I get the following error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Does anyone have a better solution for this problem?

Btw, I have the following scenario:

My client runs a server, in which he has some applications that do many different things (logging, calculations ...). He wants to be able to monitor and if needed to restart these applications from a web based client (even his mobile phone).

What I am trying to accomplish using this application is to kill a process and start the same one. Using System.Diagnostics I was able to query the processes that are currently running, but that obviously is not a solution, since for remote machines System.Diagnostics can only see processes, and not interact with them.

Comment: Anything you do on the server side will run server side. If you want to run arbitrary code on the client then you'll need to have some application on the client side that is able to dynamically determine what you're trying to do based on code snippets. Perhaps integrating something like the [CSScript](http://www.csscript.net/) project in a server running on the client would help.

Comment: Both the web site i am trying to implement and the running applications are actually running on server. Now, if I had to reimplement the applications I would probably choose to implement them as Windows Services, but unfortunately these applications have been implemented long time ago, and i do not have their source available.
One problem is that these apps are prone to crash. The requirement is to be able to detect if one has crashed, and restart it.

Comment: Then are you really trying to 'Execute a process in a remote machine using ASP .Net'? If you're client and server are on the same machine then it isn't really 'remote' is it?

Comment: :) Sorry, this title is misleading... what i try to do is to manage the processes from the same machine.

Comment: Don't tell me... fix your title.

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with WMI and get the error that you listed, generally it means that there was no data to return from your query.  Looking at your code, it seems that you never make the call to where the process data is stored.  You need to have a call to Win32_Process somewhere in your code.  The code to get info on processes goes like this:

```
ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + txtRemoteComputer.Text + @"\root\cimv2");
System.Management.ManagementScope oMs = new System.Management.ManagementScope(path, conO);
oMs.Connect();
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, query);
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
```

After that you do whatever with the code.  Please note that this code is only to get the process, I have no experience with sending calls to end a process remotely, but at least with this you can start to check if the remote computer is evening running a certain process.